# Trying to find: Short story: Boy meets a man who is about to hang himself

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

For decades this short story has been stuck in my head. We read it in highschool English class once.

As I remember it, it was about a boy leaving his home to encounter a man who was about to hang himself. I think the man is standing on a chair and preparing the ordeal, when the boy meets him. The boy doesn't understand the situation, so he starts a conversation.
Not sure how the story ends...

I remember it as a very beautiful short story, but haven't managed to find it.

Can anybody help me?

I think the word 'penny' was involved.

Does anybody know the story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. Strangely enough I never googled it like I did today, using completely different words. Alan Sillitoe, 'On Saturday Afternoon'.

A prevalent theme was also 'feeling black'.

The story is narrated by a teen remembering when he was younger.

As a kid, he followed a guy from the neighborhood who told everyone he was going to hang himself when asked about the rope he was carrying.
Being curious, he snuck into the guy's apartment, even going as far as trying to help the guy get it done.

Here's the passage mentioning a penny:

> “Shut  the  door,”  he  asked  me,  and  I  did  as  I  was  told.  “Ye’re  a  good  lad  for  your  age,”  he said  to  me  while  I  sucked  my  thumb,  and  he  felt  in  his  pockets  and  pulled  out  all  that  was inside,  throwing  the  handful  of  bits  and  bobs  on  the  table:  fag-packet  and  peppermints,  a  pawnticket,  an  old  comb,  and  a  few  coppers.  He  picked  out  a  penny  and  gave  it  to  me,  saying:  “Now listen  ter  me,  young  ‘un.  I’m  going  to  ‘ang  messen,  and  when  I’m  swinging  I  want  you  to  gi’  this chair  a  bloody  good  kick  and  push  it  away.  All  right?”

Comment: Came here to mention this. I read it in _The Loneliness of the Long-Distance Runner_.